# How to run ANOVA on multiple groups of samples, each composed by different variables

Tags: anova, normal-distribution, independence, matrix, manova

I have a $m$ x $n$ matrix, where the $n$ columns are split into multiple classes.

If I had only a $1$ x $n$ vector, I would have used ANOVA to evaluate if all subset of columns had the same population mean.
I assume that:

- samples are independent;
- each sample is drawn from a normally distributed population;
- population standard deviations of the groups of samples are all equal.

Now, I have multiple ($m$) rows in my matrix, i.e. each sample has multiple ($m$) measurements.
I thought about MANOVA or ANOVA on each row, and then use a False Discovery Rate threshold on significative pvalue. Are these correct methodologies?

Which method could I use?

Thanks

Comment: Before anyone can give you a sensical answer, I think we'll need a better understanding of what it is you are wanting to do and about the data you are looking at.  Can you describe what each of the columns are and what your objectives are a bit more?

Comment: Ok. Each column is a biological sample and it is composed by multiple measurements. Each measurement, or row, is a biological entity which can be active (positive real value), normal (around 0), or inactive (negative real value) depending on the sample.

Comment: OK.  Now what are you trying to study or learn from this data?  Don't tell us what statistical methods you think you should use.  Instead, tell us what is it that you are trying to study or investigate, while minimizing any references to statistical terminology if possible.

Comment: My objective is to find the measurements (rows) which are differently distributed in different biological samples classes (sets of columns). For instance, the rows which are mostly active in a set of samples (set of columns), and inactive in the rest of samples (rest of columns).